# What's the good choice for handling with real-time data in memory?

Tags: mysql, redis, key-value-store

Clients send some real time data to the server. The server will do simple analysis with these data. It only finds data from a specific range, or sort some data. Most of data will be abandoned after the analysis, so it's no need to save them in disk.

I want to use some memory DB to handle with them. Is the memory engine of MYSQL a good choice?  How about if I use some key-value memory cache engine such as Redis? Because I need to compare the data, maybe pure key-value store can't meet my requirement.

Comment: I'm not going to do a full answer, but you may find that MongoDB does what you want - you can stop it from flushing to disk, effectively making it an in-memory DB. The option to use is: --syncdelay 0

Answer (score 3):

To me that sounds as if it were better off without a database, but that depends on the structure of your data and what kind of operations you have to perform.

If the structure is simple and the operations easy then you should probably store the data in data structures of the programming platform you are using.

Answer (score 3):

> How about if I use some key-value memory cache engine such as Redis?

Redis supports advanced data structures which makes it a pretty handy key-value based data store, however if your data requires complex relationships then you should probably check out [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Caching), [OrientDB](http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/Concepts) or [Riak](http://wiki.basho.com/Memory.html) which should all support memory based storage engines.

Comment: I would not use Riak or OrientDB for volatile data. MongoDB or Redis are a much better choice for DIRTy applications.

Comment: OrientDB supports in-memory databases where you can use the powerful extended SQL language, Graph API, Web Studio, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to use the memory engine of MySQL, there are a few gotchas:

- by default, indexes are implemented using hash tables rather than btrees. If you need to sort the data, or range support, using btrees may be more interesting.
- locking granularity is the table. There is a R/W lock to protect against concurrent DML operations. While raw performance is not bad, scalability is not very good when you have many writers at the same time.
- all rows have a fixed width (beware if you need to store varchars ...)

Furthermore, like most others RDBMS, MySQL protocol is synchronous. Each time the clients will write into the database, they will wait for a reply. If you have a lot of data, batching writes operations is almost mandatory to get good performance.

It really depends on the volume, number of clients, and throughput. If the requirements are low, then any storage solution (including MySQL) will work fine. Now if more performance or more scalability are required, then other solutions will likely be better.

What you want to write is probably a DIRT application (data intensive real time). Good storage solutions for this are MongoDB (upserts support, oneway protocol for write operations, etc ...) and Redis (in-memory, O(1) operations, pipelining, etc ...).
Depending on your needs, data modeling and processing will be arguably easier with MongoDB due to btree indexes and map/reduce support. It will probably be a bit more complex with Redis, but if you choose the correct data structure, you will end up with more deterministic performance.

Finally, you might also want to avoid storing the data by processing them on the fly. You can achieve this with a streaming engine such as the ones used on high-speed trading platforms. For instance if you are ready to code in Java, [ESPER](http://esper.codehaus.org/) is an excellent CEP solution to process data streams and/or establish correlations between streams using a SQL-like language.

Comment: Ummm, what do you mean by **all rows have a fixed width (beware if you need to store varchars ...)**?

Does it mean that the maximum number of columns that a row can have is fixed or the maximum number of elements that I have in a varchar cannot exceed a pre-determined limit?

Comment: It means a varchar will be stored just like a char. See http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/flexibility/improved_memory_engine.html